# Como permitir cambiar el nombre al return de una funcion

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, programación-funcional, función-personalizada

Quisiera saber como permitir el uso de cualquier nombre para los valores que retorna una funcion.
Quiero lograr algo como el useState de React

```
[cualquierNombre, setCualquierNombre] = useState(initState)
```

Comment: Por favor explica mejor tu duda

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces el *destructuring* si tu función original retorna un arreglo, puedes nombrar como quieras lo que esta retorna.

Un ejemplo es lo siguiente:

```js
function returnDataArray() {
  return [
    'Cadena 1',
    'Cadena 2'
  ]
}

const [ c1, differentName ] = returnDataArray();

console.log(c1, differentName);
```

Acá la posición 0 y 1 del arreglo no están asociados a algún nombre, sin embargo estoy recibiendo estos datos mientras los asigno a variables con un nombre específico que yo escojo y con ese nombre los puedo utilizar en otra parte del código

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta